# How to declare an array whose name is contained in a variable?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Let's say, I have a variable, `arrayName = 'array1'`. Then, I wish to declare an array whose name is the value of the variable `arrayName`, i.e. `'array1'`.

I don't think

```
arrayName = []
```

will work.

I am using MATLAB, but I think this question is a generic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [eval](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) you could do it as follows:

```
   arrayName = 'array1';

   if isvarname(arrayName)
       eval([arrayName, ' = [];']); 
   end
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Thanks a lot! One follow-up question: The `if` is just to ensure that arrayName is a variable right? If I know this for sure, can I leave it out？

Comment: @FarticlePilter Yes you can. `isvarname` checks if string can be a variable, e.g. it does not start with 1.

Answer (score 4):

One other option is to use [ASSIGNIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html), which makes it easier to specify the value. In your case, you might replace EVAL with

```
assignin('caller', arrayName, magic(4));
```